# How to set Custom Adapter in ListActivity?

Tags: android, search, full-text-search, adapter, listactivity

I am trying to implement a search dialog in which I am trying to search from a given API, by making OkHttp call. But in ListActivity, I am only able to use the default adapters. Is there any way to use the custom adapter?

[image][image]

Comment: did you already make your own adapter??

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to use the custom adapter?

Create custom Adapter by extending `BaseAdapter` and pass it to `setListAdapter`.

Comment: Use retrofit to make network call . see [Retrofit— A simple Android tutorial](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23)